# Debug 404 and 502 errors in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a server running NodeJS. I have two similar errors that I do not understand. The first shows a 502:

```
[2021-03-26T11:30:09.714Z] (node:16944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 502
    at createError (/path/to/root/server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/path/to/root/server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/path/to/root/server/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[2021-03-26T11:30:09.714Z] (node:16944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
[2021-03-26T11:30:09.714Z] (node:16944) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It happened during the day at a time of some usage, but the stdout logs, with URL and user agent, do not show a request as the obvious culprit at the time of the error:

```
[2021-03-26T11:29:27.753Z] /r?u=https://vimeo.com/emotionathletes  ::  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Barkrowler/0.9; +https://babbar.tech/crawler)
[0mGET /r?u=https://vimeo.com/emotionathletes [36m302[0m 0.653 ms - 110[0m
[0mGET /health [32m200[0m 1.397 ms - 2[0m
[2021-03-26T11:30:00.688Z] /  ::  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36
[2021-03-26T11:30:42.524Z] /gift/3  ::  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
```

The second error shows a 404:

```
[2021-04-11T00:05:42.097Z] (node:30418) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/path/to/root/server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/path/to/root/server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/path/to/root/server/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[2021-04-11T00:05:42.097Z] (node:30418) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
[2021-04-11T00:05:42.097Z] (node:30418) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It happened at night with little website usage. The request seems to come from a hacker with `root@` in the user agent:

```
[2021-04-11T00:05:41.972Z] /  ::  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0 root@user-agent.ipmap.io
[0mGET / [0m-[0m - ms - -[0m
```

I log server requests to `stdout` with:

```
  let ua = req.get('User-Agent');
  console.log(req.originalUrl, " :: ", ua);
```

How can I understand the cause of the error and fix it?

Comment: It clearly indicates that you have unhandled (or maybe unresolved) promises in your code.

Comment: The cause is clear and stated in the top message. Your code isn't capturing exceptions in promises. It's taking an ostrich approach to error handling (burying its head in the sand and pretending they're not there). To fix it you have to find all code that makes requests via axios and which ignores exceptions. It's difficult to debug because the solution would be to capture the exception and log it, which would solve the problem in the first place... Perhaps you could log all outgoing axios calls using a unique string so that you can track down which one is causing the problem.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I use `axios` only through Express. The relevant route, `/`, had one promise where I used `await` and I added a catch wrapper that logs the error and the request. I'll see if that fixes it.